# Opencart - check if user is logged in and redirect to accounts page

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

My Opencart store is in a subdirectory '/login'. In the root folder I have an index.php file that displays a Login user and password interface. The site works by not allowing access until a user is logged in. Once logged in, it gets redirected to the subdirectory store.

All works fine, but when the user is finished with the site, closes the browser, and decides to come back to the .com store, they are greeted with the login interface again.

The problem lies here. If they didn't log out last time, they will be stuck at the log in screen, but because they already logged in earlier, it won't redirect if they reenter their credentials. It just errors out and fails to redirect.

So my question is: How do you check if the user is already logged in, and redirect to the site? I tried islogged() but it is undefined since all of the core files are in the subdirectory along with the rest of the store. I tried to use the php include and include the customer.php file that defines "islogged()" but that seems to not work.

Here is the code inside my index.php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'login/index.php?route=account/loginajax',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('input[type=\'text\'], input[type=\'password\']'),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#button-cart').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#button-cart').button('reset');
            },
            success: function(json) {
                $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                if (json['error']) {
                    $('.error').after('<div class="alert alert-danger has-error">' + json['error'] + '</div>');
                }
                if (json['success']) {
                    $('.error').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '</div>');
                    window.location = "http://www.mbdtesting.com/login/index.php?     route=account/account";
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What I do is use a PHP Session that is used to for the user, usually containing that uses id in the database. Then in PHP you can check by doing `if(isset($_SESSION["user"])) { /*redirect to main site*/ } else { /*redirect to login page*/ }`.

Comment: That was my initial idea, but I am not sure how to grab the user id from an isolated index.php file, when everything else is in the subdirectory. I am somehwat of a novice with php, so I am having trouble figure out how to grab the session ids.

Comment: When the user logs in create a session that stores the user id (it would be the id of the user in your database table). You would do this when the user logs in, then when they log out destroy the session.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can check is session for customer is set or not. In your index file put this :-

```
if (isset($session->data['customer_id'])) {
   /*continue to your site*/
  /**Also verify customer is valid or not then continue*/
} else {
   /*go to login page*/
}
```

Comment: I am using OC 2.x and I can confirm this method works for me. Thank you.